# Accessing the Values with a Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, promise

I am trying to fetch some data and then access the values in the response but I keep running into `Promise` which I can't seem to get out of to access my values.

Here is my request:

`var boom = fetch(uri, options).then(response => response.text());`

The response is:

`Promise {<resolved>: "{"word":"bump","results":[{"definition":"come upon…,"pronunciation":{"all":"bəmp"},"frequency":4.02}"}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: "{"word":"bump","results":[{"definition":"come upon, as if by accident; meet with"}]};`

I am not sure how I would access the value associated with "bump" or "definition". None of the normal ways I would access these values (`[]` or  `.`) seem to be working.

I am assuming this a JSON object that I can access the values from but I might be wrong; whenever I try `typeOf` I just get `object`.

Comment: The problem is, that `response.text()` returns a promise, either use `then` on it, or await it

Comment: It is still unclear how to access the values even if I do `var boom = fetch(uri, options).then(response => response.text().then());`

Comment: No, read the dupe target. `fetch(uri, options).then(response => response.text()).then(boom));` or `var boom = await fetch(uri, options).then(response => response.text())`

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. 

`var boom = fetch(uri, options).then(response => response.json().then(function(data) {console.log(data.word);}));`

Comment: Yeah, though you should omit the `var boom =` then, it's just gonna be `undefined`